# Dynamic memory allocation and function error

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
int writearray(int *array[],int a);
int main(){
    int a;
    std::cin>>a;
    int *p=new int[a];
    int i=0;
    writearray(&p,a);
    for(int i=0;i<=a;i++)
        std::cout<<p[i]<<" ";
}
int writearray(int *array[],int a){
    for(int i=0;i<=a;i++)
        *array[i]=i;
}
```

I'm getting error when i try to input integer "a". Whats wrong with my code? I'm trying to learn pointer mechanics and dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: You need to use `(*array)[i] = i;` since `operator []` binds tighter than the dereference operator.

Comment: @batuhan `int *array[]` is not what you probably think it is. Modify you progra as follows: `int writearray(int array[],int a);` then when calling pass the value of a pointer instead of address of a pointer: ` writearray(p,a);` then inside just use it as a normal array: `array[i]=i;`

Comment: The other error you have is you are using `i <= a` in two places. They need to be `i < a`.

Comment: Also, you can make your code simpler by using `int writearray(int *array, int a);` and calling it with `writearray(p, a);`.

Comment: @fukanchik Yeah that worked. I wanna ask you one more question. Why arrays working without pointer but single integer cant changing if used in another function. Like;
In int main i can set up a to "5"
Then i can write another function named change(int x) that changes integer to "0". After using change function, integer a still prints "5". I cant get it. Why integer needs pointer to change but arrays don't.

Comment: @RSahu """"Also, you can make your code simpler by using int writearray(int *array, int a); and calling it with writearray(p, a);""""
its not working at all.[Error] cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'int writearray(int**, int)'. thanks for help

Comment: See it woking at https://ideone.com/nj1AN0.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks i get it.